# Pagination not working for join 2 tables with Named query in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We tried pagination with Named query using joins but failing.

```
select laptop0_.id as id1_1_, laptop0_.brand_id as brand_id4_1_, laptop0_.name as name2_1_, laptop0_.price as price3_1_ from tbl_laptops laptop0_ left outer join tbl_brand brand1_ on laptop0_.brand_id=brand1_.id where brand1_.brand =:?

@Query("SELECT v FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and ..." )
public Page<VisitEntity> getVenueVisits(@Param("venueId") long venueId,...,
        Pageable pageable);
```

There's is no `fourign` key between 2 tables and still I want pagination using SQL joins in Spring Data `Jpa`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed pagination issue with 2 queries. One is SQL query with order by field name, sort direction, offset and limit.

Second query is to get the total records for total pages.